# Are these new edits acceptable?

Tags: discussion

[What is the naming element convention that is unique to other essential elements that are different between lifeforms from different worlds? [on hold]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/what-is-the-naming-element-convention-that-is-unique-to-other-essential-elements)

I made some edits to the following question. Are these edits sufficient for reopening the question?

Comment: No, because it does not improve the question. You really need to reformulate.

Comment: @Vincent I misunderstand what aspect of the question must be reformulated.

Comment: Maybe it's just because I was not really good in chemistry, but the whole question is very nebulous/too complicated for nothing. You are looking for a universal elemental table ? How could different species for other planets could communicate : this is hydrogen, this is ... ?

Comment: The question is looking better now and will probably get re-opened. You should consider using the sandbox as well though. http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions?cb=1 or join people in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat